# I have a problem with indentation in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm doing some scripts python3.5 based on TouchDesigner and one of them is having an indentation error. Please, I need help guys I just started to use python a few days ago. Thanks in advance.

```
# me - this DAT
# 
# dat - the DAT that received the event
# rowIndex - the row number that was added
# message - a readable description of the event
# channel - the numeric value of the event channel
# index - the numeric value of the event index
# value - the numeric value of the event value
# input - true when the event was received
# bytes - a byte array of the received event
# 
# Example:
# message  channel index value     bytes
# Note On  1        63   127       90 2f 127


def onReceiveMIDI(dat, rowIndex, message, channel, index, value, input, bytes):

            x = op('/lyricsController/Lyrics_Texts/convert1').numRows - 1

            if x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 17:
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 += 1.0
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'PASSANDO'

            elif x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 18:
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 += -1.0
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'VOLTANDO'

            elif x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 19:
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 = 0
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'RESETADO'     

 return
```

This is the interpreter feedback:

> DAT compile error: /lyricsController/midievent1_callbacks
>    File "/lyricsController/midievent1_callbacks", line 33
>      return
>           ^
>   IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>
> File "/lyricsController/midievent1_callbacks", line 33
>      return
>           ^
>   IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: One of the reasons could be using different indentations. There are 2 indentations that python supports. 1. Tab space 2. 4 blank spaces. Make sure you have the same indentation followed throughout your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read the compile error.  It says line 33 is where the error is.  Line 33 is:

```
return
```

The return statement needs to be indented too.  It should be:

```
    return
```

ie, the return statement should be indented as much as the function.

That said, in this case I don't think you even need a return statement.  Why don't you just delete it, and see if your code works as you expect it to?  I think it will.

### EDIT:

The author commented below that they tried a variety of different indent amounts for `return`, and none worked.  The reason for this is because everything else in the function was indented way too much.  Each layer should be indented by one indent, and the standard is usually 1 indent = 1 tab or 4 spaces.  So this:

```
def onReceiveMIDI(dat, rowIndex, message, channel, index, value, input, bytes):

            x = op('/lyricsController/Lyrics_Texts/convert1').numRows - 1

            if x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 17:
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 += 1.0
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'PASSANDO'

            elif x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 18:
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 += -1.0
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'VOLTANDO'

            elif x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 19:
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 = 0
                op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'RESETADO'     

 return
```

... should have been this:

```
def onReceiveMIDI(dat, rowIndex, message, channel, index, value, input, bytes):

    x = op('/lyricsController/Lyrics_Texts/convert1').numRows - 1

    if x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 17:
        op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 += 1.0
        op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'PASSANDO'

    elif x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 18:
        op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 += -1.0
        op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'VOLTANDO'

    elif x > 0 and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,0] == 'Note On' and op('/lyricsController/midievent1')[1,2] == 19:
        op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.value0 = 0
        op('/lyricsController/passadorLyrics_const').par.name0 = 'RESETADO'     

    return
```

Note: 
1. Each layer of the code is indented by a certain amount.  The first layer, e.g., `x = op(...`, is indented by 4 spaces.  Then stuff inside the `if` statement is indented by 8 = 4 * 2 spaces.  etc.
2. The `return` statement is supposed to happen not in an `if` statement but in the main body of the code, so it is indented the same amount as the main body of the code.

I was correct in saying you didn't need a `return` statement at all, but it's worth explaining why you got this error in the first place, even when you tried indenting the statement, since you will likely run into this in the future.  In fact, you can get an error like this if you use a tab to indent one line and 4 spaces to indent another!  You need to choose a rule for how you want to indent, and then stick to it.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Bro, I read this compile error but I tried everything like 4 blank spaces or 1tab space, but it didn't work. So, I removed the return like you said and worked. Thank you :)

Comment: Andre, please see my edit for a more complete explanation of the bug.  Although removing the `return` statement fixes it, the real problem is that you are not respecting indentation in general.  You may want to look at @VipulBhardwaj's answer for more information as well.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a indentation scoped language, which in plain English basically means that it uses indentation to determine which line of code belongs to what scope level.

*For example, When python reads your code, it check the indentation level to determine if that line belongs to and if or a loop or function or anything like that.*

You can read more about [here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3)